# What does 1 MB maximum size for an entity mean?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have two `blobs` each of size 0.9 MB.
Is it fine to store both in a single entity by calling

```
anEntity.setProperty( "blob1" , blob1) ; 
anEntity.setProperty( "blob2" , blob2) ; // will this hit 1 MB limit ?
```

My confusion is whether 1 MB limit is per-property or for entity as a whole.

Thanks.

Comment: It's for both, a single entity can not be larger than 1MB and given that rule then no property can be bigger than 1MB.  Also remember there is an overhead storing the key and the property name as well as the blob, so in fact a property max size will be slightly less than 1MB.

Comment: You should use the Google Cloud Storage for that case. The Datastore is not meant to store large blobs.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of having the answers as answers :

From [Tim Hoffman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201324/tim-hoffman)'s comment : It's for both, a single entity can not be larger than 1MB and given that rule then no property can be bigger than 1MB. Also remember there is an overhead storing the key and the property name as well as the blob, so in fact a property max size will be slightly less than 1MB.

From [Gilberto Torrezan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1013327/gilberto-torrezan)'s comment : You should use the Google Cloud Storage for that case. The Datastore is not meant to store large blobs.

Comment: Thanks Tim Hoffman and Gilberto Torrezan for your clarifications.

Comment: However, the real use case is this. 
In my application, a user keeps appending a string to an entity, once per invocation. In about one month after deployment, I seem to run the risk of hitting 1 MB size limit. I can visualise how to cope with this programatically. It is clumsy though. I am sure many would have encountered similar problem. Can someone throw light how he went about ?
Thanks.

Comment: Change your data model from appending a string to an entity to something else. Keep appending into a "row" will be a problematic for all system because the data is only keep growing and will hit limitation